# How to connect contour lines from two different sources?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation, lidar, contour

How to connect contour lines from two different sources (LiDAR & Photogarametry) in order to obtain continuous and uniform contour lines layer ? how can i interpolate them together ? How can i Snap lines only if they have the same Height value ?

[image: contours from 2 sources]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the distance between the lines in your two data sources can vary greatly (at least it looks like this on the picture), you might need to do some manual work. However, I'd suggest trying the [Extend line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001v00000004000000) GP tool (Editing toolbox) or [Snap tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Snap/001v00000007000000/) (same toolbox).

> This tool extends line segments to the first intersecting feature
>   within a specified distance. If no intersecting feature is within the
>   specified distance, the line segment will not be extended.

You might also test to use the [Load Objects](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003n0000003r000000) to load features from one source to another and set snapping settings. I use it quite often when "merging" road datasets from different sources and it reduces amount of manual work that will be needed to get done anyway.

There is a great blog post from [Esri](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/11/15/cleaning-up-line-data-with-geoprocessing/), where you can get more tips on data processing for such cases. They mention also using [Integrate tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002s000000), [Trim line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Trim_Line/001v00000008000000/) and some [other custom GP tools](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=48a27060aaca4500ae3017489799f2fb) the Esri Editing team has published.

Answer (score 1):

If you have both shape files you can merge the shape files and do the contour again.

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't good agreement between the datasets you can't really expect much, but all these vector solutions are pretty labour intensive. I would create two DEMs and mess with some masking in the interface area of the 2 data sets to set up some averaging or weighting rules based on initial results.
If you want quick and dirty convert both rasters to points... select all the points in the overlapping area and delete them, then run topo2rater on the points and create new contours out of the output DEM